# How can I create automatically expiring user accounts?

Tags: users, account-restrictions, accounts, guest-account

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

After a user's account is created, they should be able to `ssh`-tunnel, but their account is automatically removed after 30 days unless the countdown is reset by the root user.

How can I automate this? I'll have to handle around 15 users.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### useradd

You can control how long a user's account is valid through the use of the `--expiredate` option to `useradd`.

*excerpt from `useradd` man page*

```
-e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
     The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
     specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

     If not specified, useradd will use the default expiry date specified
     by the EXPIRE variable in /etc/default/useradd, or an empty string 
     (no expiry) by default.
```

So when setting up the user's account you can specify a date +30 days in the future from now, and add that to your `useradd` command when setting up their accounts.

```
$ useradd -e 2013-07-30 someuser
```

#### chage

You can also change a existing accounts date using the `chage` command. To change an accounts expiration date you'd do the following:

```
$ chage -E 2013-08-30 someuser
```

#### calculating the date +30 days from now

To do this is actually pretty trivial using the `date` command. For example:

```
$ date -d "30 days"
Sun Jul 28 01:03:05 EDT 2013
```

You can format using the `+FORMAT` options to the `date` command, which ends up giving you the following:

```
$ date -d "30 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"
2013-05-28
```

#### Putting it all together

So knowing the above pieces, here's one way to put it together. First when creating an account you'd run this command:

```
$ useradd -e `date -d "30 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"` someuser
```

Then when you want to adjust their expiration dates you'd periodically run this command:

```
$ chage -E `date -d "30 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"` someuser
```

#### Specifying time periods of less than 24h

If you want a user to only be active for some minutes, you cannot use the options above since they require specifying a date. In that case, you could either set up a `crontab` to remove/lock the created user after the specified time (for example, 10 minutes), or you could do one of:

```
adduser someuser && sleep 600 && usermod --lock someuser
```

or

```
$ adduser someuser
$ echo usermod --lock someuser | at now + 10 minutes
```

#### References

- [useradd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)
- [chage man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chage)

Comment: I took the liberty to change the %M (Minutes) into %m (month)

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Debian/Ubuntu you should use `adduser` and `usermod`. On Debian based systems `useradd` is considered low level and (according to the man pages): `administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead`

`adduser` has a no expiration option, so you just use it to create the account.

`usermod` has the `-e` / `--expiredate` option to set the expiration date.

You calculate the parameter to `date` with: `date -d "30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d"` to get:

```
usermod --expiredate $(date -d "30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d") username
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way (if your OS does not support account expiration or this feature doesn't work for whatever reason): set up a cron job to run 30 days from now that will lock this account.

Usually the account is locked by setting its encrypted password to invalid value; on FreeBSD, `pw lock X` command will lock the account `X`.

Comment: Explain how you can lock an account.

Comment: That's OS-dependent, really.

Comment: It would still be helpful if you gave an example showing it.